# Template deduction fails for known argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

Consider following code

```
template<typename T>
T modify(const T& item, std::function<T(const T&)> fn)
{
    return fn(item);
}
```

When trying to use it as `modify(5, [](const int& i){return 10*i;});` it fails to compile with

> could not deduce template argument for `'std::function<T(const T &)>` from `lambda`

I know that compiler can not deduce `T` from lambda, because lambda is not `std::function`, but isn't `T` already deduced from `5`?

I can get over it using

```
template<typename T, typename F>
T modify(const T& item, const F& functor)
{
    return functor(item);
}
```

for which previous example compiles, but it is in my opinion less intuitive. Is there a way to let the function argument to remain `std::function` and have it's template argument deduced automatically from `item`?

Comment: Using a separate template argument for the "predicate" is how the standard library does it. If you look at all [algorithmic functions in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) you will see that all that takes a predicate takes it as a separate templated type. However all those functions are well specified and documented, making the "intuitive" point moot. Good documentation is the key here IMO.

Comment: `std::function` is not an efficient solution when the functor type is known. Concepts will eventually solve the intuition problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you basically want to do is prevent deduction from happening. If template deduction occurs, it will fail (because a lambda is not a `std::function<>` - it doesn't matter that `T` was deduced from the first argument, deduction must succeed in every argument that is a deduced context). The way to prevent deduction is to stick the entire argument in a non-deduced context, the easiest way of doing that is to throw the type into a *nested-name-specifier*. We create such a type wrapper:

```
template <class T> struct non_deduce { using type = T; };
template <class T> using non_deduce_t = typename non_deduce<T>::type;
```

And then wrap the type in it:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const T& item, std::function<void(T)> f);

template<typename T>
void bar(const T& item, non_deduce_t<std::function<void(T)>> f);

foo(4, [](int ){} ); // error
bar(4, [](int ){} ); // ok, we deduce T from item as int,
                     // which makes f of type std::function<void(int)>
```

---

Note, however, that:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
void quux(const T&, F );
```

is not really any less readable, and strictly more performant.

Comment: I'd have made the "don't do it" warning even stronger, but +1.

Comment: Why isn't `F` passed as `const F&` in `void quux(const T&, F );`?

Comment: @Zereges Why would it be?

Comment: Consider calling `quux(5, foo)`, where `foo` is instance of functor with `operator()` and possibly some data, which would be copied if passed as value. Right?

Comment: @Zereges Yes. What if `foo`'s `operator()` is non-`const`? I could see the argument for `F&&`, not for `F const&`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using the `identity` trick as below:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity {
  typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
T modify(const T& item, typename identity<std::function<T(const T&)>>::type fn) {
  return fn(item);
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc3a3263ceb28fbf)